# How to use Visual Studio editor to replace and keep part of a string

Tags: regex, visual-studio

For example, I want to replace `\s}` to `}` for only those in `[^\s]\s}`. How to do it in visual studio?

Comment: You mean `(?<!\s)\s}`? Remove whitespace before `}` if it is not preceded with another whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General idea is to use *capturing groups*:

*What*: `([^\s])\s}`
*With*: `$1}`

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%29%5Cs%7D&i=Text%20%7D&r=%241%7D)

Here, `([^\s])` (equal to `(\S)`) is a *capturing group* with ID = 1 that matches any non-whitespace symbol and stores it inside a memory slot that can be addressed with a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1` from the replacement pattern.

In this case, to remove a whitespace symbol before `}` if it is not preceded with another whitespace, you may use a lookbehind based regex, `(?<!\s)\s}`, and replace with `}`.